# How to fix [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml, xv-11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to run the following launch file: hector_neato.launch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="xv_11_laser_driver" type="neato_laser_publisher" name="xv_11_node">
    <!--<param name="port" value="/dev/tty.usbserial-A9UXLBBR"/>-->
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
    <param name="firmware_version" value="2"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="laser"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_2_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /laser 100"/> 
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d rviz_cfg.rviz"/>
  <include file="default_mapping.launch"/> 
  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch"/>
</launch>
```

When I run it it gives me the following error

```
while processing default_mapping.launch: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'default_mapping.launch' The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

This doesn't make sense because the file that it's complaining about is in the same directory as hector_neato.launch which is

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share/hector_slam_launch/launch
```

Please help.

---

Edit: Never mind I fixed it. I just got rid of the include and copy and pasted `default_mapping.launch` into `hector_neato.launch`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226290/how-to-fix-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [jaymo3141](https://answers.ros.org/users/25794/jaymo3141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I was missing the "/launch/" in the path. Don't know why I didn't see it.

Also the two launch files hector_neator.launch and default_mapping.launch came from this project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSlkjY-78SQ (see comments section)

Thank you all for your help.

---

Originally posted by [jaymo3141](https://answers.ros.org/users/25794/jaymo3141/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0